# Storm DRPC Clients

Tags: apache-storm, drpc

I am working on Storm, creating a topology with a DRPC stream. I have created the topology, deployed it, and I have a Java `DRPCClient`. All of this is working fine, both for local and remote.

However, I am interested in other methods of accessing the DRPC server. Are there any methods other than the Java `DRPCClient` I mentioned previously? I've been Googling but I can't find any information about this, so any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One client we frequently use is **node-drpc** for node.js.

It can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-drpc